# Dynamic Column Name in where clause and column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My Query would be like below and i have 50 combination (L1,L2,L3.. L50) with different where clause and different column name,

Can you please suggest me , how to WRITE easy method to achieve and reduce the process time ?

L1 A and L1 B colunm name would be same ,But L1 C column names are Totally different. Similar like other levels as well.

Ex: l2 A,L2 B,L2 C, ...... L50 A etc

```
 Declare @SQL max set @sql = ' SELECT '+@InputColumn+',

    19 AS [LEVEL],    --- Dynamic column name change
    'L1 A' AS NAME , --- Dynamic column name change
    BP_GEO AS [GEOGRAPHY],
    BP_CTRY AS COUNTRY ,
    BP_DIV AS DIVISION,
    BP_BU AS BUS ,
    BP_BUSINESS AS BU_LC_EC,
    BP_SEG_NEW AS SEGMENT ,
    FROM #Dummy(NOLOCK) 
    WHERE BP_SEG_NEW = GCP_SEG_NEW  --- Dynamic column name change

           UNION ALL

    SELECT    '+@InputColumn+', 

    19 AS [LEVEL],        --- Dynamic column name change
    'L1 B' AS NAME ,      --- Dynamic column name change
    BP_GEO AS [GEOGRAPHY],
    BP_CTRY AS COUNTRY ,
    BP_DIV AS DIVISION,
    BP_BU AS BUS ,
    BP_BUSINESS AS BU_LC_EC,
    BP_SEG_NEW AS SEGMENT,
    FROM #Dummy (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE BP_SEG_NEW <> GCP_SEG_NEW AND GCP_SEG_NEW = 'KUMAR'-- Unable to pass 2 condition in the where

           UNION ALL 

    SELECT    '+@InputColumn+', 
    19 AS [LEVEL],            --- Dynamic column name change
    'L1 C' AS NAME ,          --- Dynamic column name change
    GCP_GEO AS [GEOGRAPHY],   --- Dynamic column name change
    GCP_CTRY AS COUNTRY ,     --- Dynamic column name change
    GCP_DIV AS DIVISION,      --- Dynamic column name change
    GCP_BU AS BUS ,           --- Dynamic column name change
    GCP_BUSINESS AS BU_LC_EC, --- Dynamic column name change
    GCP_SEG_NEW AS SEGMENT,   --- Dynamic column name change
    FROM #Dummy(NOLOCK) 
    WHERE BP_SEG_NEW <> GCP_SEG_NEW --- Dynamic column name change 

    UNION ALL  --- level 20

    SELECT '+@InputColumn+',

    20 AS [LEVEL],    --- Dynamic column name change
    'L2 A' AS NAME , --- Dynamic column name change
    BP_GEO AS [GEOGRAPHY],
    BP_CTRY AS COUNTRY ,
    BP_DIV AS DIVISION,
    BP_BU AS BUS ,
    BP_BUSINESS AS BU_LC_EC,
    BP_SEG_NEW AS SEGMENT ,
    FROM #Dummy(NOLOCK) 
    WHERE Global = GCP_SEG_NEW  --- Dynamic column name change

           UNION ALL

    SELECT    '+@InputColumn+', 

    20 AS [LEVEL],        --- Dynamic column name change
    'L2 B' AS NAME ,      --- Dynamic column name change
    BP_GEO AS [GEOGRAPHY],
    BP_CTRY AS COUNTRY ,
    BP_DIV AS DIVISION,
    BP_BU AS BUS ,
    BP_BUSINESS AS BU_LC_EC,
    BP_SEG_NEW AS SEGMENT,
    FROM #Dummy (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE Global <> GCP_SEG_NEW 
    AND GCP_SEG_NEW = 'KUMAR'-- Unable to pass 2 condition in the where

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT    '+@InputColumn+', 
    20 AS [LEVEL],            --- Dynamic column name change
    'L2 C' AS NAME ,          --- Dynamic column name change
    GCP_GEO AS [GEOGRAPHY],   --- Dynamic column name change
    GCP_CTRY AS COUNTRY ,     --- Dynamic column name change
    GCP_DIV AS DIVISION,      --- Dynamic column name change
    GCP_BU AS BUS ,           --- Dynamic column name change
    GCP_BUSINESS AS BU_LC_EC, --- Dynamic column name change
    GCP_SEG_NEW AS SEGMENT,   --- Dynamic column name change
    FROM #Dummy(NOLOCK) 
    WHERE Global <> GCP_SEG_NEW --- Dynamic column name change 

    EXEC (@sql)
```

How to combine L1 A ,L1 B,L1 C in one select statement with dynamic column name and where clause ?

Please see the sample query for your reference.

Note: Above Query only one combination i have given ,similar like i have 50 combination to write the code with union all.

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Are the "dynamic" values changing because some application is feeding in different values, or are they changing just so you can construct a static query without having to type everything out?  If it's the latter, you will generally improve processing time the more you type stuff out.

Comment: Hi Muqo, Please look into my updated Query.. Query will be static Till level 50 . I am planning do Dynamically changes the column name and where clause. Example: See the example Static Level , LCT , Where clause i need to hardcode. how to avoide hardcode and get dynamically

Comment: @Venki Maybe you could express with another example what you want to accomplish. Could you define the problem you intended to solve with this approach?